# Is there a way to have web.config values overwrite app.config values?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have a web project that references a dll project that uses an app.config value.  Is there a way to put the app.config values in the web.config so when the web project is run it pulls the values from the web.config?  I've heard of this happening but I'm not 100% sure of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) attribute/property of each config element - this allows you to put sections of your configuration in an external file.

Once in an external file, you can reference this file from both your `web.config` and `app.config` files.

Comment: This can also be done using XPATh as well at least for updating nodes within the .config file

Comment: @DJKRAZE - How do you mean? Parsing out `.config` files as XML files?

Comment: Would it be possible to reference the web project properties using the configSource?

Comment: @NullReference - I don't understand what you mean. Did you read the documentation I linked to?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a wasy - but to open manually the app.config file ( if your start entry point is the web...)

so youll have to open each section and analze it.